# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException exception in Xamarineforms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarine. 
I had created new blank Xamarine project in Visual studio 2019.
I am using this link to create demo native views in Xamarine forms : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml

**MainPage.Xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:UIKit;assembly=Xamarin.iOS;targetPlatform=iOS"
             xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
             xmlns:androidLocal="clr-namespace:App1.Android;assembly=App1.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <ios:UILabel Text="Hello World" TextColor="{x:Static ios:UIColor.Red}" View.HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <androidWidget:TextView Text="Hello World" x:Arguments="{x:Static androidLocal:MainActivity.Instance}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I had added skip Xamlcomplitation in **MainPage.xaml.cs** file.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
```

Added in MainActivity.cs in App1.Android file.

internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }  // define Instance

[image]

Bit it shows error for

```
 ( 8976): Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0xd1e768c0] -> System[0xe4b32b00]: 5
**Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException:** 'Position 15:52. Type MainActivity not found in xmlns clr-namespace:App1.Android;assembly=App1.Android;targetPlatform=Android'
```

Comment: the namespace for `MainActivity` is `App1.Droid`, not `App1.Android`.

Comment: I replaces it with this. I am not getting any error . But not able to see the label for Android when i run the project. xmlns:androidLocal="clr-namespace:App1.Droid;assembly=App1.Droid;targetPlatform=Android"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
```

Is something that you add to the Xaml backend code. Adding it to something else like in your case is likely to cause problems.

Comment: I had added this to App.xaml.cs . I needed to add that in MainPage.xaml.cs . Adding that  and .Droid instead of App1.Android solved my problem